# How i can POST (send the file to server) a video in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift2

How i can POST (send the file to server) a video in swift 2.0? I have the url of the file. How  i can GET the video in server side.

```
    //url from server
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://myurl/uploadvideo.php") 
    //video url
    let pathString = blabla.relativePath
```

Usually i post with JSON like this:

```
    let parameters = ["Nombre":"\(nombre.text)", "Correo":"\(correo.text)", "Edad":"\(edad.text)", "Mensaje":"\(mensaje.text)"] as Dictionary<String, String>
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setBodyContent(parameters)

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let strData =
        NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Body: \(strData)")
        print("account data")
        if(error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
        else {

        }

    })
    task.resume()
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Check out NSURLSession's static `uploadTaskWithRequest()` methods.